# WordPress ACF Google Maps Radius Search

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

i got a big Problem and have no Solution.
i work with **WordPress** and **Custom-Post-Type (CPT)** and **Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)**.
I create a new CPT called "projekt" and a **ACF "Google Map Field"** which saves the **Adress, longtitude and latitude**. The bad thing is ACF Fields were saved **serialzed** in the MySQL DB.

**i found the following SQL-Query on the Net to calculate the Radius.**

```
$lat = '50.12335';
$lng = '-1.344453';
$radius = 10; // (km)  

???....WHERE ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
* cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) 
- radians(" . $lng . ") ) 
+ sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= " . $radius . ")"
```

i don't know how to build the query, because the query needs to get the longtitude and latitude info from the serialized ACF fields.

**DB-Field "meta_value":**

```
a:13:{s:7:"address";s:44:"Moskauer Straße 5, Düsseldorf, Deutschland";s:3:"lat";d:51.2199565;s:3:"lng";d:6.8044928;s:4:"zoom";i:14;s:8:"place_id";s:114:"EiNNb3NrYXVlciBTdHIuLCBEw7xzc2VsZG9yZiwgR2VybWFueSIuKiwKFAoSCZV-jR3Ny7hHEVVgUQUBF7q8EhQKEgkBGQXwtsu4RxHgwS1K_GAnBQ";s:4:"name";s:16:"Moskauer Straße";s:11:"street_name";s:16:"Moskauer Straße";s:17:"street_name_short";s:13:"Moskauer Str.";s:4:"city";s:11:"Düsseldorf";s:5:"state";s:19:"Nordrhein-Westfalen";s:11:"state_short";s:3:"NRW";s:7:"country";s:11:"Deutschland";s:13:"country_short";s:2:"DE";}
```

**i can get all my "projekt"'s with:**

maybe it's possible to extend the following query

```
SELECT P.ID, P.post_title, P.post_content, P.post_author, meta_value
FROM wp_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM on PM.post_id = P.ID
WHERE P.post_type = 'projekt' and P.post_status = 'publish' and ( meta_key = 'adress' )
ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
```

**result is:**

```
ID|post_title  |post_content|post_author|meta_value
55|Test Projekt|            |1          |a:13:{s:7:"address";s:44:"Moskauer Straße 5, Düss...
```

Do you got any Solution for me ?

Thank You!

Comment: Can you post what the data looks like in the DB?

Comment: I've updated my Post with the serialized String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution by myself.
Most People, create extra Tables with lat and long.
I think that's senseless because they are already there in the acf field.
i'm not very skilled in MySQL so some people can shorten the query of course.
i dont know how to use varibales in MySQL so the regex for lat and long can be put into a Variable:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL), '.+\"lat\";d:([0-9\.]+).+','\\1') AS latitude

REGEXP_REPLACE(IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL), '.+\"lng\";d:([0-9\.]+).+','\\1') AS longitude
```

here is now the complete query for Radius Search with WordPress , ACF (Google Map field), where INPUTLAT,INPUTLONG,INPUTKM are the values you deliver:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.post_title, P.post_content, P.post_author,
    IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL) AS adress,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL), '.+\"lat\";d:([0-9\.]+).+','\\1') AS latitude,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL), '.+\"lng\";d:([0-9\.]+).+','\\1') AS longitude
FROM wp_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM on PM.post_id = P.ID
WHERE P.post_type = 'projekt' and P.post_status = 'publish' and IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL) IS NOT NULL and IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL) IS NOT NULL AND 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(INPUTLAT) ) 
* cos( radians( REGEXP_REPLACE(IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL), '.+\"lat\";d:([0-9\.]+).+','\\1') ) ) 
* cos( radians( REGEXP_REPLACE(IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL), '.+\"lng\";d:([0-9\.]+).+','\\1') ) 
- radians(INPUTLONG) ) 
+ sin( radians(INPUTLAT) ) 
* sin( radians( REGEXP_REPLACE(IF(PM.meta_key = 'adress', PM.meta_value, NULL), '.+\"lat\";d:([0-9\.]+).+','\\1') ) ) ) ) <= INPUTKM 
ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
```

**This Just work at MariaDB or MySQL 8. MySQL 5 dont know REGEX_REPLACE**

Comment: Adding lat and long in a separate table isn't senseless at all. As long as they are indexed, it makes more sense then trying to do everything in one query. 1. It simplifies the SQL meaning less risk of introducing errors, but 2. even more importantly it is a more optimised query which will *improve performance*. The database is required to do *much* less work to do the query, requiring less memory, reducing the load on the database and taking much less time improving its speed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this looks pretty nasty but in testing with out adding the radius portion Im able to extract the `lat` and `lng` from the serialized data.

[image]

So I think you can tack on your radius check as an `AND` something like below:

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pm.meta_value, 'lat', -1), ';', 2), ':', -1), '"', '') AS latitude,
  REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pm.meta_value, 'lng', -1), ';', 2), ':', -1), '"', '') AS longitude
FROM wp_postmeta pm
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'change_to_your_meta_key'
AND ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) 
- radians(" . $lng . ") ) 
+ sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
* sin( radians( longitude ) ) ) ) <= " . $radius . ")"
```